# Error when sharing Sheet with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When sharing a Google Sheet with a button that runs a Google Script I run into the following problem:
- When anyone but myself clicks the button the script will return the following error:
"You are trying to edit a protected cell or object. Please contact the spreadsheet owner to remove protection if you""

I had a couple protected ranges (deleted them now) in the sheet, but not one even close to the button.
I've tried to add a button on one of the shared user's account and copied the script into a new script file (re-linking the script created/copied by the shared user to the button created by the shared user), but to no avail.

Anyone who knows the solution to this problem ?

Comment: Share the file... or a test

Comment: Link to the file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZPPvk_2dSbY15mNP2stkopu90IZbN3z6HdB3ZFD51QM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Removing the protection doesn't work just by deleting the cell values. There's a sample code in [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection) which shows adding and removing protection in sheet ranges:

```
 // Remove all range protections in the spreadsheet that the user has permission to edit.
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
 for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
   var protection = protections[i];
   if (protection.canEdit()) {
     protection.remove();
   }
 }
```